# How to return an empty Object rather than Null when doing a Left Join

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a field: "Country" of an Entity class that is optional. The country refers to a table containing a list of ids with country attributes.

In order to include the rows in my table where no Country has been given I used:

```
.....createAlias("country_Id", "Co", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
```

I would prefer an empty Country object to be returned instead of just null for the country field of the Entity object.

For starters is my approach getting all the table rows, those with/without a country correct?
Or is there a better method?

Finally would you advise creating an interceptor to turn null into a Empty Country Object? Otherwise I will just handle it in my code that handles the returned search results, by adding an IF(null) statement.

Comment: I suggest you to check if the value of that column is null, then do `Country c = new Country();` or `Country c = countryDAO.create();` if you are using DAO and you have a method to create empty objects (as I have in my project). Finally, just have to `...setCountry(c);` and return the object that contains that Country/empty Country.

Comment: i.e run this check once the search results have been returned to me and I begin to process the results?

Comment: Exactly. When the query ended, then proceed to check for your elements if they have Country as `null` and add it an empty object. If it is only for a `get(KEY_TYPE id)`, just use an `if` and add it. If you are using a `findAll()`, you will have to use a loop and it's not a really good idea, but I don't know if there is any other way to do that (any method or XML property for `hbm` files).

Comment: Yeah I agree. It would work and is easy to implement, so i will probably have to go with this method. I just hoped there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Would creating an interceptor to overwrite the onLoad() method do the trick?

Comment: Do you mean override your current method? (i.e.)`@Override public void onLoad(){...}`

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `COALESCE` function to return a new Country if the field is null : 
`SELECT COALESCE(Co, new Country()) ...`. But you may have to bind your main Entity to the Country entity instead of using the `country_Id`.

[EDIT]
It can be used with a CriteriaBuilder also : 
`cb.coalesce(root.get("Co"), new Country())`
/!\ will use the same default Country instance for all result lines

Comment: Can `COALESCE` be added as a parameter to a Criteria object?

Comment: This looks like a good answer, however I'am using the hibernate Criteria Library and wouldn't want to change to this java jpa one.